# How to define this 'var' type formally?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

This code:

```
var items = query.ToList();
```

returns `List<'a>` where `'a is new { string a1, string a2 }`

If I were to remove the `var` keyword, what would be a valid type definition to use here that keeps the names `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: You cannot determine an anonymous type at compile time.  That's a main reason `var` was added.  You can replace the anonymous type with `Tuple` or a custom class though.

Comment: @juharr I think it would be safer to say that `var` exists only for types that *can* be determined at compile time (try using it with one that can't). IIRC it predates anonymous types by a version or two.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, my wording should be before compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning an [**anonymous type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) and therefore you do not know the type name at compilation time. If you want to remove the `var` project to a custom type instead of an anonymous type.

If you are in need to remove the `var` and know the type then do not use anonymous types. Have a look at: [Why use anonymous types instead of creating a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21443117/6400526)

---

To use something along the lines of your comment: `List< { string a1, string a2 } >` look into Named Tuples in C# 7.0. You have have a look under [C# 7.0 new features](http://New%20Features%20in%20C#%207.0) or [Better naming in Tuple classes than "Item1", "Item2"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745938/6400526)

Something along the following:

```
List(string a1, string a2) result = (from item from collection
                                    select new (string a1, string a2) 
                                        { "firstString", "secondString" }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you not use something along these lines `List< { string a1, string a2 } >`? `

Answer (score 10):

Nothing, because it's a list of an anonymous type. The very term "anonymous type" was chosen because the type doesn't have a name.

If you want to be able to use explicit typing, don't use an anonymous type. Either create your own type, or (in C# 7) use a C# tuple type. (The regular `System.Tuple` type wouldn't let you preserve the names you want.)

Comment: Realistically I just wanted an easy way to make it a class variable instead of a local variable. I could reprocess it with a loop into a different structure, I just thought there might be a simplistic method.

Comment: @Nicholas - no need to reprocess it. Perhaps update question with query

Comment: @Nicholas: No, you simply can't declare variables that use anonymous types as type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The point about anonymous types is that they are *not* available at design time (when writing the code). They will be provided somewhere hidden by the compiler when the code is compiled. They *have* a name, and they are properly designed, but the types are inaccessible at design time by design.

That’s why you are using `var`; to let the compiler figure out what type this actually is, since the compiler is the only instance here that can tell you “where” the type is.

If you *could* replace the `var` by something real at design time, then you could also replace the `new { … }` by `new Whatever { … }` which would make this type no longer anonymous. – So if you *want* to use a type instead of `var` there, define an actual type yourself. Remember that doing that does not actually have a difference to what the compiler does for you anyway; it’s just you now who is writing that class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way is to downcast the result to non-anonymous ancestors of `List<'a>` type - `IList` or `IEnumerable`:

```
IList items = query.ToList();
```